# Set DateTimeIndex in existing DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a existing dataframe, df, which consists of the following structure:

```
   tick_id    stock_ticker        tick_datetime  price  volume
0   160939   A2M AU Equity  2016-10-19 09:00:00  450.0   79700
1   160940   A2M AU Equity  2016-10-19 09:00:01  450.0     100
2   160941   A2M AU Equity  2016-10-19 09:00:01  450.0    2500
3   160942   A2M AU Equity  2016-10-19 09:00:01  451.0     200
```

What I am looking to do is to set the "tick_datetime" as the index of the dataframe, so that it should become DateTimeIndex for easier data manipulation later.

However, executing the following command yields unexpected result.

```
df.set_index('tick_datetime')
```

What is the correct way to achieve my desired outcome?

Comment: Describe this unexpected result.

Comment: Nothing has been changed. I was expecting that after the command, 'tick_datetime' would be set as the index of the dataframe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
df['tick_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['tick_datetime'])   
df.set_index('tick_datetime',inplace=True)
```

or:

```
df['tick_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['tick_datetime'])
df = df.set_index('tick_datetime')
```

Comment: Thank you. However, is there any way that I could set it so that it becomes a DateTimeIndex?

Comment: Sure. Add `df['tick_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['tick_datetime'])` to your code.